# Movement of enemy issue

Tags: python

I have a game im making but for some reason the enemy, when it goes down it should start going up but it doesnt. It just starts blinking.
Code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Yues")
theboard = pygame.image.load('theboard.png')
enemy = pygame.image.load('mrenemy.png')
mrhinckleberg = pygame.image.load('MrHinckleBerg.png')
mrhincklebergdead = pygame.image.load('MrHinckleBergdead.png')
black = (0,0,0)
def quitt():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
enemydirection = 'down'
enemyx = 500
enemyy = 50
while True:
    window.blit(theboard, (0,0))
    if enemydirection == 'down':
        enemyy += 60
        if enemyy >= 790:
            enemydirection = 'up'
    elif enemydirection == 'up':
        enemyy -= 60
        if enemyy >= 10:
            enemydirection = 'down'
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your upper boundary detection. Change

```
if enemyy >= 10:
```

to

```
if enemyy <= 10:
```